# How to read giant text file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, file-io, fread

I have few text files with size more than `30MB`.

How can i read such giant text files from PHP?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you need to work with all the data at the same moment, you can read them in pieces. Example for binary files:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/foo/bar/somefile", "rb");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $block = fread($handle, 8192);
  do_something_with_block($block);
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

The above example might break multibyte encodings (in case there's a multibyte character across the 8192-byte boundary - e.g. `Ǿ` in UTF-8), so for files that have meaningful endlines (e.g. text), try this:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/foo/bar/somefile", "rb");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $line = fgets($handle);
  do_something_with_line($line);
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: As far as I know, `fgets()` will still mess it up if the file's encoding does not have ASCII-compatible, one-byte line endings, e.g. UTF-16.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the file using [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), read the lines using [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

```
$fh = fopen("file", "r");  // open file to read.

while (!feof($fh)) { // loop till lines are left in the input file.
        $buffer = fgets($fh); //  read input file line by line.
        .....
        }       
}       

fclose($fh);
```